# CA1034 is not being shown, even with <AnalysisMode>AllEnabledByDefault</AnalysisMode>

Tags: c#, .net-core, code-analysis, .net-5, roslyn-code-analysis

I've created the class given as an example by Microsoft:

```cs
internal class ParentType
{
    public class NestedType
    {
        public NestedType()
        {
        }
    }

    public ParentType()
    {
        NestedType nt = new();
    }
}
```

But no warning seems to be generated. I'm using Visual Studio 2019. The framework this code is being tested on is .NET 5

Comment: Do you mind if I go ahead and raise this issue in the docs - probably submitting a PR - or would you like to have the honor since you've spotted it?

Comment: Created PR https://github.com/dotnet/docs/pull/23752

Comment: @FlashOver sorry, I was away on the weekend. Thank you though.

Comment: I hope I haven't jumed the gun - and wasn't all too happy on that PR trigger finger - however, the PR has been approved and merged.

Comment: @FlashOver good to know! In the end what matters is that we end up improving the .NET community :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning [CA1034](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1034) only gets reported on externally visible nested types, which are declared within another externally visible type.
Since your enclosing type is `internal`, your nested type cannot be accessed from outside of this assembly either, therefore the rule is not violated.

You will see the diagnostic being reported when you make the enclosing type `public` as well:

```cs
public class ParentType
{
    public class NestedType // Warning CA1034
    {
    }
}
```

So I believe you've discovered an error in the example of the official docs.

**Update:** The official docs are now updated with the fixed example code.